# Freetype2 Access Violation after FT_Load_Char in debug mode only

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-debugging, freetype2

Having some trouble with an implementation of FreeType2 for an X-Plane plugin.  I'm using a freetype implementation I didn't write, but the good news is, it works...in release mode.  I cannot get past this point in debug mode, which means I can't debug any other parts of my program.  If anyone has any ideas on what could be going wrong or how I can prevent the problem from occurring in debug, that'd be great.  Here's the code:

```
// We iterate through every letter that we care about
// and record the tallest letter and the width of all
// letters combined as well as the widest letter.
for(int n = FM_BASE_ASCII_RANGE; n <= FM_PEAK_ASCII_RANGE; ++n)
{
    if(FT_Load_Char(*inFace, n, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
        continue;

    // If the bitmap doesn't exist, we have nothing to do
    //access violation happens when executing the next line in debug
    if(!(*inFace)->glyph->bitmap.rows || !(*inFace)->glyph->bitmap.width) 
        continue;

    int width  = (*inFace)->glyph->metrics.width / 64.0;
    int height = (*inFace)->glyph->metrics.height / 64.0;

    // If any of the sizes are 0, we have nothing to do
    if(!(*inFace)->glyph->metrics.width || !(*inFace)->glyph->metrics.height)
        continue;

    if(height > maxHeight)
        maxHeight = height;

    // Add this to our sum with some room for padding as well
    curRowWidth += width + FM_PIX_PADDING;

    // If it doesn't fit, we add a new row and put it there
    if(curRowWidth > FM_DEFAULT_TEX_WIDTH)
    {
        nRows++;
        curRowWidth = width + FM_PIX_PADDING;
    }
}
```

The code above is called for each font and loops through the letters to calculate size I believe. The error happens first time through with the first font that's loaded. Font rendering works great and looks great in release mode.

I'm not sure if it matters, but if I break before this access violation and evaluate (*inFace)->glyph->bitmap, I see that rows and width are 0...but bitmap.buffer is listed as 0x0000~ .

Also, n is 32 on the first iteration of the loop. FT_Load_Char comes back with no error.

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 with the Windows 7.1 SDK in Win 7 64 bit and this is a 64 bit project.  I just upgraded to freetype 2.5.3 but had this same problem with my previous version 2.4.12.

If anyone can help, it would help me a lot, thanks!

Edit:  Here's the disassembly section around the error while running:

```
for(int n = FM_BASE_ASCII_RANGE; n <= FM_PEAK_ASCII_RANGE; ++n)
000007FEE531F29A  mov         dword ptr [n],20h  
000007FEE531F2A2  jmp         FontMgr::CalcTexSize+6Eh (7FEE531F2AEh)  
000007FEE531F2A4  mov         eax,dword ptr [n]  
000007FEE531F2A8  inc         eax  
000007FEE531F2AA  mov         dword ptr [n],eax  
000007FEE531F2AE  cmp         dword ptr [n],0FEh  
000007FEE531F2B6  jg          FontMgr::CalcTexSize+178h (7FEE531F3B8h)  
{
    if(FT_Load_Char(*inFace, n, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
000007FEE531F2BC  mov         r8d,4  
000007FEE531F2C2  mov         edx,dword ptr [n]  
000007FEE531F2C6  mov         rax,qword ptr [inFace]  
000007FEE531F2CB  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rax]  
000007FEE531F2CE  call        FT_Load_Char (7FEE5360790h)  
000007FEE531F2D3  test        eax,eax  
000007FEE531F2D5  je          FontMgr::CalcTexSize+99h (7FEE531F2D9h)  
        continue;
000007FEE531F2D7  jmp         FontMgr::CalcTexSize+64h (7FEE531F2A4h)  

    // If the bitmap doesn't exist, we have nothing to do
            if(!(*inFace)->glyph->bitmap.rows ||!(*inFace)->glyph->bitmap.width)
000007FEE531F2D9  mov         rax,qword ptr [inFace]  
000007FEE531F2DE  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]  
000007FEE531F2E1  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+6Ch]  
->000007FEE531F2E5  cmp         dword ptr [rax+60h],0  
000007FEE531F2E9  je          FontMgr::CalcTexSize+0BDh (7FEE531F2FDh)  
000007FEE531F2EB  mov         rax,qword ptr [inFace]  
000007FEE531F2F0  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]  
000007FEE531F2F3  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+6Ch]  
000007FEE531F2F7  cmp         dword ptr [rax+64h],0  
000007FEE531F2FB  jne         FontMgr::CalcTexSize+0BFh (7FEE531F2FFh)  
        continue;
000007FEE531F2FD  jmp         FontMgr::CalcTexSize+64h (7FEE531F2A4h)
```

Comment: You probably have some uninitialized memory that is triggering a condition in debug mode that is not in release. The debug Visual C++ runtime actually initializes allocated memory with various non-zero bit patterns depending on how it was allocated/freed. If you examine the local variables are there any that have weird values like **0xcdcdcdcd**?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything.  Would it be in that routine? I'm seeing a lot of pointers that are 0x000000~ with a lot of zeros. And of course there's the Bad Ptr for the bitmap.buffer.